# alert for both android and IOS in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hai i am trying to show alert message, i tried different ways like alert,AlertIOS,Alert.alert

- AlertIOS is working in IPhone but not working in android and alert also same
  In Docs i saw that Alert.alert will work for both Android an IOS,But i got an error like undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Alert.alert')
  I wrote like this:

> ```
> Alert.alert('Alert', 'email is not valid, Please enter correct email', [{text: 'Ok'}]);
> ```

I got an error like this:

[image]

Any one give suggestions that how to show the alert in Android and IOS in react-native
Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 18):

Are you sure you are including it from the correct path?
I get the same error when I imported Alert from react library and NOT react-native.

so the working thingie is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Alert } from 'react-native';
```

and the non-working one was:

```
import React, { Component, Alert } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you forget to import `Alert` from `react-native`

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

and then you can show Alert like this

```
Alert.alert("Alert message");
```

Answer (score 0):

We just need to **import** it correctly:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

Then use it in your project as written in your code and it will work for both platforms :

```
Alert.alert('Alert', 'email is not valid, Please enter correct email', [{text: 'Ok'}]);
```

refer: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert