# Alert.alert() not working in React Native 0.36.1

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am trying to use the [Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html) component in React Native to create a consistent experience between Android and iOS. I am trying to run the example alert. I import the Alert component (omitted other imports for brevity):

```
import {
  Alert, 
} from 'react-native';
```

I then create the alert provided in the example:

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ]
)
```

However, I get the following error:

[image]

I have found [this post with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473690/alert-for-both-android-and-ios-in-react-native), however, I believe my problem is different because:

- I am running React Native version 0.36.1
- I am seeing this error for Android and iOS

I am stumped as to how to fix this. Has anyone else had any luck getting this to work on version 0.36?

**Update**

As requested, here is an example of where I am trying to use the alert:

```
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} underlayColor='transparent'   onPress={() => Alert.alert(
        'Alert Title',
        'Alert Message'
      )}>
```

This is just one instance where the code fails. I have tried multiple alerts across several components and methods and none of them are working.

**Update 2**

It is worth noting that the standard `alert()` function works without crashing. However, I am not able to specify the title of the alert. For instance the code below would return an alert with a title "Alert" and the message as "Please enter a 4 digit code".

```
      alert("Invalid Code", "Please enter a 4 digit code.")
```

My desired output would be to have the title = "Invalid Code" and the message = "Please enter a 4 digit code."

Comment: Can you provide more context where you are using the Alert. For example also include code of component and function where you are calling alert

Comment: @coderhacker Please see my update.

Comment: Well you're definitely importing it and using it correctly...I would try restarting the packager and sim. If that doesn't work, maybe try doing `react-native upgrade` to check whether you're template files are up to date with your npm package.

Answer (score 2):

I would try creating a separate function that calls for the Alert.alert('foo'). Then in your TouchableHighlight, use `onPress={this.onYourFunctionName.bind(this)}`